# How to break a condition without a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
//Controller le nom et prenom
                NomPrenom = document.F1.T1.value;
                if(NomPrenom === "") {
                    alert('Le champ Nom et Prenom ne doit pas être vide');
                }
                NomPrenomArray = NomPrenom.split("");
                for (i=0; i<=NomPrenomArray.length; i++) {
                    if (isNaN(NomPrenomArray[i]) === false) {
                        alert("Nom et Prenom doit être une chaine");
                    }
                }

                //controller l'âge
                Age = document.F1.T2.value;
                if(Age === "") {
                    alert("le champ age est obligatoire");
                }
                if(isNaN(Age) === true) {
                    alert("le champ age doit être un valeur numerique seulement");
                }
                if((Age<20) || (Age>30)) {
                    alert("l'age doit être supérieur ou egale a 20 et inférieur ou egale a 30");
                }
```

> > If one condition is false it will continuing appearing others alert.

How to avoid this for exemple (if `name input == ""`) then it will show first alert and the second alert etc... 
But i want it to stop only at the false alert can you help and thank you !

Comment: Is this really how you indent your code? Good luck debugging ;-)

Comment: You can use `else if ` instead of `if ` for all cases.

Comment: if else block might be one you are looking for

Comment: You have more closing braces than opening.

Comment: You can use any indentation/formatting you like in your own code, but when asking for help, reformat it into any of the several reasonable, readable formats. (I would do that for your own purposes as well, those braces are placed to actively encourage bugs.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this, is to put all that code in a function, and add a  `return` whenever you want to exclude the rest from executing:

```
//Controller le nom et prenom
function validate() {
    var NomPrenom = document.F1.T1.value; // Declare!
    if (NomPrenom == "") {
        alert('Le champ Nom et Prenom ne doit pas être vide');
        return;
    }
    var NomPrenomArray = NomPrenom.split(""); // Declare!
    for (var i=0; i<=NomPrenomArray.length; i++) { // Declare i!!
        if (!isNaN(NomPrenomArray[i])) { // Use `!`
            alert("Nom et Prenom doit être une chaine");
            return;
        }
    }

    //controller l'âge
    var Age = document.F1.T2.value; // Declare
    if (Age == "") {
        alert("le champ age est obligatoire");
        return;
    }
    if (isNaN(Age)) { // No need for `== true`
        alert("le champ age doit être un valeur numerique seulement");
        return;
    }
    if (Age<20 || Age>30) {
        alert("l'age doit être supérieur ou egale a 20 et inférieur ou egale a 30");
        return;
    }
    return true; // All OK
}
```

Then make sure to call this function at the right place:

```
validate();
```

NB: `alert`s are really not user-friendly. Consider outputting the error message on the page itself, maybe in red, near the `input` element that has the validation error.

Comment: Ok ! i will try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use while something like this:

```
boolean default = false;

while(!default) {
  /*  
   *  all your logic will go here and then
   *  make it as true, where you want to break it
   */
  default = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
function verif1() {

    NomPrenom = document.F1.T1.value;
    NomPrenomArray = NomPrenom.split("");
    Age = document.F1.T2.value;

    //Controller le nom et prenom
    if (NomPrenom == "") {
        alert('Le champ Nom et Prenom ne doit pas être vide');
    } else if {
        for (i = 0; i <= NomPrenomArray.length; i++) {
            if (isNaN(NomPrenomArray[i]) == false) {
                alert("Nom et Prenom doit être une chaine");
            }
        } else if (Age == "") {
            alert("le champ age est obligatoire");
        } else if (isNaN(Age) == true) {
            alert("le champ age doit être un valeur numerique seulement");
        } else if ((Age < 20) || (Age > 30)) {
            alert("l'age doit être supérieur ou egale a 20 et inférieur ou egale a 30");
        }
    }
}
```